# Kendo Combo Box Load Child Based On First Combo Box

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I'm fairly new to kendo I have a requirement to load Kendo Combo box lazily.
Here is the scenario:

I have two combo boxes `Cmb 1` and `Cmb 2`.
`Cmb 1` has parent data and `Cmb 2` has child data.
My requirement is to load `Cmb 2` data only after selecting `Cmb 1` selection.

In the data source level how can I achieve that? Is there any facility provided by the Kendo framework itself?

Please advise. If someone can provide me a solution that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo provides cascading comboboxes. You can see how it works in this demo:
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/cascadingcombobox.html